# Consider linear equation $x'+a(t)x=b(t)$.Find $\psi$ function class $C^1$ such that the equation $\psi(t)x'+\psi(t)a(t)x= \psi(t)b(t)$ is exact.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider linear equation $$x'+a(t)x=b(t)$$ where $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ are continuous functions. Find $\psi$ function class $C^1$ such that the differential equation
$$\psi(t)x'+\psi(t)a(t)x= \psi(t)b(t)$$ is exact. Then find the general expression of the solutions of the given differential equation.

I would like a script to solve this problem, I'm lost, help

Answer (score 0):

The central concept for an integrating factor is to turn the left hand side into a product rule.  If you see $3t^2y + t^3y'$, you might spot that that is $(t^3y)'$, for example. So $c(t)x' + c'(t) x = (c(t)x)'$. So the question becomes, starting from $$x' + a(t)x = b(t)$$, how do we find $\psi(t)$ such that $a(t)\psi(t)$ is the derivative of $\psi(t)$?

We turn that statement into a new equation:$$a(t)\psi(t) = \psi'(t)$$ which is separable.  The result is: integrate a(t), then put that in an exponent.  So $\psi(t) = e^{\int a(t) dt}$.  That is the general formula for an integrating factor for this kind of equation.

You should memorize this approach, it is useful again later.